# Can't edit a existing PDF file with FPDI

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

I am trying to learn how to edit a PDF file with FPDF and FPDI using PHP language.  I have this [sample PDF file](https://i.ibb.co/nMK5XB9/pdf.png) where I want to insert some values. If I were to create a PDF file using FPDF, everything works fine. But if I try to edit an existing PDF file using FPDI, it gives me the following error message: `This page isn’t working. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ( ). crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.` The following shows two programs for editing PDF files. The first one works and the second one fails.

```
<?PHP
  //This program works and create a new PDF file.
  require('fpdf.php');
  $pdf = new FPDF();
  $pdf->AddPage();
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
  $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
  $pdf->Output();
?>
```

The following program for editing an existing PDF file fails:

```
<?PHP
      require_once('fpdf.php'); 

      //This second line of code fails.
      require_once('../fpdf183/FPDI/FPDI-2.3.6/src/Fpdi.php'); //This path is correct. I have tested it out with a simple echo “hello world”; file. 
      //I assume I didn’t install fpdi correctly. I have tried replacing /Fpdi.php part with autoload.php as well. 


      $pdf = new FPDI();
      $pdf->AddPage(); 
    
      $pdf->setSourceFile('testfile.pdf'); 
      $tplIdx = $this->pdf->importPage(1); // import page 1 
      $this->pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0, 0, 0, true); 
      $this->pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', '13'); 
      $this->pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
      $this->pdf->SetXY(20, 20); //set position in pdf document    
      $this->pdf->Write(0, 'Some texts will go in here');    
      $this->pdf->Output('newfile.pdf', 'D');//force the browser to download the output
    ?>
```

First I have downloaded FPDF .zip file from [fpdf.org](http://www.fpdf.org/) and extracted it in my hosting file server. Then I downloaded FPDI from [setasign.com](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/downloads/) website and uploaded this .zip file to my hostinger online webserver. Then I have extracted it inside the same fpdf folder. (zlib extension is enabled in my server).

Comment: For your 2nd PHP (the one you say it fails), please replace all the `$this->pdf->`by `$pdf->` and retry

Comment: @KenLee Thank you for the reply. After the change, I still get the same error. If I delete all the codes and just leave the following line of statement `require_once('../fpdf183/FPDI/FPDI-2.3.6/src/Fpdi.php');` in my PHP file, I still get the same error:

Comment: Do you have another version of fpdi ? (the one like this : `require_once('vendor/setasign/fpdi/fpdi.php');`

Comment: @KenLee No, I don't have another version and this fpdi. The one I downloaded doesn't have a folder called `vendor/seatasign/..` either. https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/downloads/

Comment: Please see the suggested way in my answer. Thanks

Comment: Just enable PHP errors to see the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A. FPDI download**

After you download the fpdi from say https://github.com/Setasign/FPDI, please use the following to get the fpdi started:

```
require_once 'FPDI-master/src/autoload.php';
require_once('FPDI-master/src/fpdi.php');
```

The following is a fully working example which I have used in the past **for your reference** (I've used TCPDF, but I have changed to use fpdf):

**B. Testing PHP: testgen.php**

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
//require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');

require_once('vendor/setasign/fpdi/fpdi.php');


$pdf = new FPDI();


$pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile('ok.pdf');

for ($n = 1; $n <= $pagecount; $n++) {
$pdf->AddPage();


$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($n);
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx);

$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', 'B', 10);

$pdf->SetXY(150, 10);
$pdf->Write(0, "Appendix 1(new)");
}

$pdf->Output("output_sample_ken.pdf", "D");

?>
```

In order to faciliate you to further test it, you may download the fpdf / fpdi files from this link:

```
http://www.createchhk.com/SO/pdfpack_20June2021.zip
```

after that, unzip and upload the files to your webserver PHP folder, then use a browser to run the testgen.php to see the effect. (the php will add the text `Appendix 1(new)` on each page of the original `ok.pdf` file, and then download the file)

**C. Problem in processing Encrypted PDF**

Last but not least, please note that **FPDI does not support importing of encrypted PDF documents** see the following link:

https://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/can-fpdi-import-encrypted-pdf-documents/

In my experience, to process an encrypted pdf, you may use something like pdf995 to "print" the encrypted pdf so as to generate a normal pdf, then this latter pdf can be processed by FPDI.

Comment: I have downloaded the files from github site you mentioned and extracted them into a different folder in my hosting server. When I use `require_once 'FPDI-master/src/autoload.php';` it works fine. I can even have a test file in there that outputs a "Hello World" to the screen, so the path is correct: `require_once('FPDI-master/src/echohello.php');`. However, whenever it encounters this other line: `require_once('FPDI-master/src/fpdi.php');` it gives that same error message: This page isn’t working, ..... Can you please tell me from where did you get these `vendor/autoload.php` files?

Comment: I have revised my answer by adding a download link of zip file (containing both fpdf and fpdi). Please try

Comment: Thank you for going this extra mile. I really appreciate it. Your code and any code I write works well with this `ok.pdf` file you have attached. There are no issues. However, if I try to use any pdf file other than your `ok.pdf` file, I get that same error. For example, can you try your code with this pdf file from adobe site: https://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/knowledgecenter/media/c4611_sample_explain.pdf

Comment: The pdf in your link points to an encrypted pdf. (if you check the source of this particular pdf you will see the /Encryp flag) The fpdi documentation has stated that it does not support importation of encrypted pdf. I have just revised my answer to point out this. (and included in my answer one of the ways to tackle this problem)

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining your answers with sample code and putting all these efforts. I really appreciate all you did. You are a big help.